# unicode conversion in tamil from Latha font to Kal fonts

Tags: c#, unicode, fonts

i'm using latha font for tamil typing ,I need to change latha font to Kal (Another font family). But it doesn't work for me,also i'm trying to convert latha to unicode to kal.
Need some code in c#

Comment: This depends on the encodings of the fonts. If they are both Unicode fonts (Unicode encoded fonts), no conversion is needed. If not, you need to know exactly what the encodings are.

Comment: Solved. Developed a converter for latha font to kal font. Added support in textbox with google input tools with tamil language.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert text only use < http://software.nhm.in/products/converter >. It handles many encodings and it is free.
Some manufacturers provide Unicode version of their font also in addition to the original encoding.
 
If you need to type in Latha font using a different Keyboard interface then get the free layout driver from < http://www.thamizha.com/project/ekalappai > 
My own < http://www.mediafire.com/download/jjaqdbuk99062ki/Tamil_Driver_1.03.zip > You can type in Inscript Keyboard mode
Give more details about  Kal fonts.

Comment: Solved. Developed a converter for latha font to kal font. Added support in textbox with google input tools with tamil language.